# How to find the difference between two matrices using python and limit the iteration with an absolute cutoff of 0.005?

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am writing a python code for explicit Euler's method, where I got struck with a particular step. How can I find the difference between two consecutive matrices (2x1)? The algorithm states if I can reach the difference to 0.005, then I can stop iterating the values for the variables (Euler's method to solve two dependent differential equation).

Here is the code: The problem is, when I am using the while loop.

```
import array as arr
from array import *
import numpy as np


#storing the T (tau) value:

T= arr.array('d', [0.18,0.16,0.14,0.12,0.10,0.08,0.06,0.04,0.02,0.001]) #time step

I= [[1, 0], [0, 1]]

A= [[-1, 10], [1, -10]]

w0= [[0.2], [0.8]]
w1= [[0.0], [0.0]]

D= np.subtract(w0, w1)
s=0;

for i in range(0, 1):
    B =np.multiply(A, T[i])
    C= np.add(I, B)

    while(D[0][0]>=abs(0.005) and D[1][0]>=abs(0.005)): #to specify the cutoff value
        D= np.subtract(w0, w1)
        w1= np.matmul(C, w0)
        w0=w1
        s=s+1; #to trace the number of iterations

    
        
print(w0)
print(s)
```

Comment: `abs(0.005) == 0.005`. Did you mean `abs(D[0][0]) >= 0.005`?

Comment: Yeah it can be vice-versa. But, the the loop only ran for two iteration but I need the loop to get continued until I reach that difference condition.

Comment: it can't be vice versa, though: `abs(D[0][0])` is the absolute value of `D[0][0]`, it cannot be negative. `abs(0.005)` is the exact same as `0.005` itself. So, if `D[0][0]` goes below zero, that condition will be met immediately, which is not what you want.